# Sending email with sendgrid on Azure using PHP returning status code 0

Tags: php, azure, sendgrid

my PHP application is hosted on Azure and I'm using [SendGrid PHP client](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php) to send emails to the application users. Everything was working fine till yesterday evening and suddenly after that emails have stopped working. On further debugging I found that the following piece of code

```
$response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);
echo $response->statusCode();
```

is returning statusCode as zero. 0 as I understood is not returned by the server. To cross check I sent test mails through my local XAMPP PHP server and it worked well. So I assume that Azure is not able to reach sendgrid servers.

Please note that the same code was working till yesterday evening and neither code changes nor setting changes were done to trigger any issue.

To reproduce the issue, I have created a simple procedure

```
public function test_sendgrid_email(){  
        $api_key = '***************************'; //Hidden for security reasons
        $request_body = [
            'personalizations' => [
                [
                    'to' => [
                        [
                            'email' => 'test@example.com',
                            'name' => 'Test'
                        ]
                    ],
                    'subject' => "Sending with SendGrid is Fun"
                ]
            ],
            'from' => [
                'email' => 'example@test.com',
                'name' => 'Example'
            ],
            'content' => [
                [
                    'type' => 'text/html',
                    'value' => "and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP"
                ]
            ]
        ];

        $request_body_formatted = json_decode(json_encode(($request_body)));

        $sg = new \SendGrid($api_key);

        try{
            $response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($request_body_formatted);                
            return ['status' => 'success', 'message' => 'status code : ' . $response->statusCode()];
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            return ['status' => 'failure', 'message' => 'Failure'];
        }            
    }
```

Output: {"status":"success","message":"status code : 0"}

Is there any thing that has to be changed in Azure settings to get it back working? Any recent updates to Azure environments that forced this issue ?

Comment: Please see: [Response status code 0 #348](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/issues/348).

Comment: It worked fine when I made the call to Sendgrid using CURL. It fails only for Sendgrid PHP library. So I have started using CURL in my application.